# How to import certificate chain and private key into java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, tls1.2

I have the a cert chain (.chain) and a private key (.private) file for my ssl, is there any way I can load those into keystore?

Comment: Have you tried https://keystore-explorer.org/ and it's "Import Keypair" (OpenSSL) function?

Comment: yes I did. but im getting could not load the unencrypted private key.

Comment: What format(s) are the contents of these files? In particular, are they both [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail)?

Comment: no they are not both pem. its .chain ( which i was able to add on my keystore ) and .private

Answer (score 0):

You dont explain your context precisely therefore I will give an standard answer:

You usually need a .cer file that includes the whole chain of certificates (ROOT, INTERMEDIATE and CERTIFICATE itself) concatenated in one file. When you have that file (usually after creating a CSR from the server, so that the cert will work with it, and get it signed by the cert authority) you can use the following to import:

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

Comment: That only works if the keystore entry already contains the privatekey (usually with a dummy or obsolete cert), which the Q implies it does not, and also the file is PEM or DER cert, cert sequence, or p7b/p7c (PKCS7/CMS SignedData with no data and no signature only certs)